# Tell me beforehand when I max out the number of tags

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

5 is the maximum number of tags on a question but you don't find that out until you go to submit your question. Then you lose all of the tags and have to start all over again retyping the tags.

This is a minor nuisance and it woulf be nice if there were a warning statement while you are adding tags so you know when to stop  and submit the question.

Comment: I think that it is only necessary for it to not make you lose the tags.

Comment: Exactly, thats a good reason for the warning. A users time should never be needlessly discarded.